# Perl open not running shell commands

Tags: perl

Why does the following perl script not print anything?

```
if (open(my $fh, "| (while read LINE; do echo \$LINE; done )")) {
    print $fh "test";
    close($fh);
}
```

In `sh`, if I run `echo 'test' | (while read LINE; do echo \$LINE; done )` I would expect to have `test` be printed out.

Comment: Add "\n" to your print, like this `print $fh "test\n"`;

Comment: Side note, `open my $fh, "|-", ".."` as perl favors three args `open`. (`"-|"` to rad from pipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "\n" to your print, since `read` is looking for a whole line, like this

```
print $fh "test\n";
```

Comment: It is best to `$fh->autoflush` so that you can print what you want

Comment: @Borodin, The thing is, `test`+newline is what he wants to print. `$fh->autoflush` won't help at all here.

Comment: @ikegami I have removed the erroneous part of the explanation - thank you for pointing it out.